WebSocket doesn't work after http request
I am working on my project ASP.NET + react, where I am going to use WebSocket and http requests. If I use only websocket, it works.
However, if I send http request at once and then try to connect websocket, I get an error

websocket connection failed

I have this component:
const Component = () => {
    const webSocket = useRef<WebSocket>();

    useEffect(() => {

        function GetSomeData():Promise<any>{
            const res = axios.get(host + "getSomeData", {
                withCredentials: true
            })
            return res;
        }

        GetSomeData().then(() => {
            webSocket.current = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:7094/ws");
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="Component">
            Test Component
        </div>
    )
}

I have a controller on the server side that looks like this:
[HttpGet]
public  async Task WebSocketConnection()
{
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        string userId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId");

        using (var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
        {
            await HandleWebSocketConnection(webSocket, userId);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
    }
}

private async Task HandleWebSocketConnection(WebSocket webSocket, string userId)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

    while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        
        webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}

I tried to send http request without websocket. It works.
I tried to connect websocket without any http requests. It works.
However, when I send http request and then connect websocket, I get an error

websocket connection failed

I tried to connect websocket after some timeout, but it still doesn't work.

Do you encounter any CORS issues? And whether the proxy is configured?
